# How to pass parameter from launcher to updater with Install4J

Tags: install4j

We have an installer that installs two launchers.
Each launcher launches one updater, the same for the two launchers.
At the end of the update process, so at the end of the installation when the case, we would like to execute the good launcher, i.e. the one which was previously launched.

Is it possible to do that, for exemple with passing a parameter from the launcher to the installer through the updater ?

Or should we create a dedicaced updater for each launcher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which kind of update-downloader you are using:

**1. Update downloaders with immediate execution of the new installer**

To pass information from the launcher to the new installer, you can call the update downloader with arguments like

```
-Vname=value
```

that set installer variables.

You then have to pass that information to the downloaded installer that is executed with a "Run executable" action by passing extra arguments like this:

```
-Vname=${installer:name}
```

Then, these installer variables will be available in the new installer.

You have to call the update downloader with the API, the automatic launcher integration does not allow adding these parameters.

**2. Background update downloader**

If you use the "Background update downloader", you can call

```
UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(...)
```

with the `restartLauncher` argument set to `true` to restart the same launcher after the update, and with the `launcherArguments` argument you can pass additional arguments.

For GUI launchers, you can configure that this call is made automatically at startup on the "Executable info->Auto-update integration" of the launcher wizard.

Comment: We use "automatic integration" for the updater, i don't see where we can add args like "-Vname=value" i may miss something

Comment: You cannot use the automatic integration in that case, you have to call the update downloader explicitly. The "Start integration wizard" button will give you code snippet for calling the update downloader.

Comment: I have expanded my answer to include background update downloaders

Comment: T h a n k s sir